# REST API - Post Requests to Query Active Directory

Tags: rest, post, get, active-directory

My company is currently writting a REST API where they allow querying for Active Directory specific information via a POST requests.

In the request body the following information gets sent to the API:

- Filter (LDAP)
- Properties to return (e.g userAccountControl, sAMAccountName)

From a personal point of view I would have definitely realised it via simple GET methods.

Is the POST method approach the recommended way to so? Are there any particular reasons to implement it with POST?

Answer (score 1):

I can see slight advantages of using a POST request. It is certainly more secure for sending any sensitive data, because the body of the request is not cached by the user's browser and other network devices on the way. Also a POST request allows you to send an unlimited amount of data, but that is probably not relevant for this use case.

Comment: Was considering the browser history and eventuall log files along the way. To me the query just doesn't seem to be much more sensitive than any other GET Request. Really would like to hear some general opinions.